# What is the velocity of a translating projectile in 2D?

Tags: java, libgdx, mathematics

**What I'm trying to do.**

So I want to have a projectile that starts at point (x1, y1) and *head in the direction of my mouse say point* (x2, y2).

To clarify I'm pretty sure it's a vector but I don't know much about them.

**Language / Librarys**

I'm making the game in Java and LibGDX so Java.MathUtils would come in to play i'm pretty sure. If anyone that can answer don't know these languages, psuedocode will be just fine.

**How I've tried it**

I'm pretty sure the formula is something alongs the lines of 
velX := cos(radians) * speed
velY := sin(raidans) * speed

And radians starts out as Pi/2 though the tutorial was pretty rough.

Then it would be x += velx * deltatime  and same with y.

**Can anyone help me out with the translation formula**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn a little bit more about vectors but I'm going to explain it anyways.

First of all, let's say that your 'game unit' is in *pixels* and that `points` (coordinates) and `vectors` have *two components* `x` and `y`.

Let's assume that you have two given `points` A = (x1, y1) and B = (x2, y2).

To get the vector between A and B, you have to do the following formula: `V = B - A`. Since B and A have two components, we can translate this into `V = (xB-xA, yB-yA)`

[image]

However, this vector is pretty much useless because the length of it is the length of the line between A and B. If you have something like this

```
V = mouse.pos - projectile.pos
projectile.pos += V
```

it will instantly move the projectile to the mouse because - well - you're asking to move the projectile to the mouse..

The idea here is to get a `direction` from your projectile (point A) to your mouse or whatever object (point B).

[image]

So.. how do we get this direction ? Well, it's easy, the formula is `u = V/length(V)`

This procedure is `normalizing` where you just get the `direction` of a vector and completely ignore its length (sometimes called 'magnitude').

Adding this vector `u` to your position will move your object **1 unit** away from its current position.

The point of it ? Moving your projectile towards a point with a fixed 'speed', like this:

```
projectile.pos += u * 10;
```

this code will move your projectile **10 units** (let's say pixels) towards your mouse.

---

EDIT: Note that with this method you don't need to use trigonometry to compute the normalized vector; that means that neither you have precision loss (floats, pi, ...) nor confusing conversions with radians. That's a win :)

---

EDIT2: For consistence and clarity, I used the word vector and position but these "concepts" are the same: a point has an X and Y component as well as a vector.

In the code you would use the same data structure. Unfortunately I don't know java but I can provide you a c++ example:

```
struct MyData //That would be public class in java I beleive
{
    float x;
    float y;
}
```

Here MyData is a structure that allows two components: x and y. This structure is used for points as well as vectors; eg:

```
MyData point_a;
MyData point_b;
MyData vector_between;

//Instantiate and/or initialize values ...

vector_between = point_b - point_a;
```

In C++ there is a concept (operator overloading) that makes you able to perform custom operations between data structures (such as `point_b - point_a` in the above example). This is really useful because the program won't know how to subtract two "MyData" together unless you write your own method.

I don't think Java enables you to do this "hack", so instead of

```
vector_between = point_b - point_a;
```

you could write

```
vector_between.x = point_b.x - point_a.x;
vector_between.y = point_b.y - point_a.y;
```

this is what I meant where I directly used "pos" without the associated component.

Moreover, when I used `length(V)` I meant `sqrt(V.x*V.x + V.y*V.y)`, that is the *length/distance* between two points (Pythagorean theorem, right ?)

NB: Usually the `MyData` data structure is, by "convention" called a `Vector2` in 2D, `Vector3` in 3D etc...

Comment: You are a legend.

Comment: Is a vector a coordinate or a direction and how do i translate and X and Y coordinate by this , there isn't a .pos is there? Isn't it just a .x and .y

Comment: Let me restate, projectile.pos += u * 10; is what you said for translation but i don't understand .pos , I'm not using sprites, just raw for loops for projectiles and X&Y Coordinates.

Comment: Length of what? From point a to point b as a line?

Comment: Edited my post, take a look at it :) In this case, the "pos" was a "MyData"/Vector2 instance

Comment: No yeah i know the length of a line formula but I guess im just gonna write my own normalize function that so would it look something like this:            for x : 'd = pointb.x - pointa.x' 'v = normalize(d) * speed' 'x+=v'

Comment: You just need to take each component and divide it by the vector length, like `v.x /= length; v.y /= length;` **make sure that length != 0** (=do a simple check) *[didn't see your edit]*

Comment: Got it to work, you my friend are jesus christ. Thank you for dealing with me.

Answer (score 0):

To get from point `A` to point `B` where both A and B are vectors, the direction  is the vector `normalize(B - A)`, lets call it `C`. The velocity you're looking for is the direction-vector `C` times the speed in units per second.

So if `A` is your actual position, `B` is your target position, `10` is the speed in units per second and `delta` is your deltatime, then your velocity is `velocity = normalize(B - A) * 10;`  and your new position is `A + velocity * delta`.

Comment: What is Normalize, I can't find it in the java docs. & Would I do the same formula for both X & Y

Comment: Do i do this velocity formula for both X & Y??

Comment: You do this once for the __vector__ (x, y). Also, normalize is a function known in vector math, so either read about vector math or let your vector-library do it for you, I'm sure it has a normalize function.